# Preloader in Drawer (mui react)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have a Drawer build in mui and also I want to put preloader before fetch data. When click on button open drawer and show blank page 1-2s then load data. The Loading component is corect without issue

This is my code:

```
interface SummaryState {
summary: Summary;
open: boolean;
loading: boolean;
}

class Info extends React.Component<any, SummaryState {
static contextType = AuthenticationContext;
subId: string | undefined = undefined;

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        summary: { unreadNotifications: 0 },
        open: false,
        loading: false,
    };
}

render() {

    return (

            <DrawerLayout
                title="Data"
                anchor="right"
                onDrawerToggle={() => this.setState({ open: false })}
                open={this.state.open}
            >
                {this.state.loading ? (
                    <Loading />

                ) : (
                 
                        <Details />
              
                )}
            </DrawerLayout>

    );
}


fetchSummary = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true }, () => {
        Repository.fetchSummary()
            .then((response) => this.setState({ summary: response.data, loading: false }))
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
                this.setState({ loading: false }); 
            });
    });
};
```

The Preloader not show when loading is TRUE.
Any idea how to fix this?